# Lookup filter not working as expected

Tags: lookup-filter

I have an object (Object A which has a checkbox field Active). I have referred this field in another object through a lookup.
In the filtered lookup condition, I have put Active=True. However, during fetching the results it is bringing all the values(active and inactive).
The error message which I have written in lookup filter shows up when I am saving the record with an inactive record.
What I understood from online documentations, is that it should restrict the values from appearing in the lookup itself, but it prevents me only during saving of the record.
Kindly suggest if this is the correct behaviour and if so, how do I get around this.

Comment: How are the fields defined (with names please) in your two different fields on both objects? Please edit your question (click on edit at bottom left) to update it with the information. E.G. is the 2nd one a checkbox formula field?